# Checking File Permission on Windows for non elevated users

Tags: c++, windows, file-permissions

I am writing some C++ code for the Windows(XP/7) platform to check the permission associated to a file. I want to verify that the file I am reading cannot be written by accounts with non elevated privileges. This is what I am currently doing:

- I get the DACL associated with the file calling **GetNamedSecurityInfo**
- I call **CreateWellKnownSid** with well known Sids, such as **WinAuthenticatedUserSid** (the Users group)
- I call **BuildTrusteeWithSid** to build a TRUSTEE with the previous SID
- I call **GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl** with the previously created trustee to get the effective acl
- I check that the ACL does not contain the Write Flag set.

This code is working perfectly for the Users group. What about the other groups such as Everyone, Guests, or other specific users which may have specific write access on the file? I would like to find a solution where I don't need to enumerate all possible SID and check against all of them. Is there a SID I could use such as "anything but not admin"?

Regards,
Ant

Comment: The file could have a permissive ACL for a single user. If you rely on `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`, that implies you must check all users individually. Also, it sounds like you could just offload all the hard work to [`AuthzAccessCheck()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375788(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a slightly different approach:

1. Get all ACE's via `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`, for the file and all its parents
2. Select the `GRANT_ACCESS` and `SET_ACCESS` ACE's
3. Get the list of trustees from the selected ACE's
4. For each of the trustees, perform an access check. `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` is probably the easiest solution here.

You'll want to think specifically what you want to do with the OWNER. He can alter the rights at any time.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. In this case, if I want to allow only elevated accounts to have write access, for each TRUSTEE I should still check whether they are part of the Admin group or any other group part of the Admin group. Is it correct?

Comment: @user1230896: I don't think so. Administrator on Windows is not Unix' root. Its special position lies in the fact that it can _take_ ownership. Unlike root, it has no automatic access.